# Enumeration with subtypes c#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, enums

First of all perhaps this is a problem due to a bad design.
Here is my scenario simplified:

I have a class call Day it represent a day of the year, with its date and the "type" of day.

```
public class Day{
 Date Key;
 TypeDay type;
}
```

So the day can be a worked day or a holiday one:

```
public enum TypeDay{
    Work,
    Holiday
}
```

So far so good, but now holiday days can have subtypes like paidDays and NonPaid days
I would need another enum to represent that subtypes or add all subtypes in a single enum (in this example i have 2 days and 2 subtypes but in real live i have 50-40 types) so this get so messy .

```
 public enum TypeDay{
        Work,
        Holiday_NonPaid
        Holiday_Paid
    }
```

How can i build this in a better way,any ideas?

Comment: `Paid` could be an attribute of `Day`: You can have a property on `Day` named `IsPaid`. If you have other combinations like this. They may also need to be a property.

Comment: Enumerations are nothing more than labels for specific numeric values. Nothing prevents you from storing 42 in the `Day.type` field. There are no subtypes. *Don't* use an enum if you want to represent a hierarchy. Although in this case, you have a calendar with various date types. These are too dynamic to be stored in a hard-coded enum. What about lockdown days? They aren't holidays, they aren't work days, but some were paid and some not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agree that but they dont have "identy" to be a class they just represent a state of a day thats why i stored as a enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerators didn't support that behaviour, If you feel that a structure like that is needed you can 'simulate' it with a static class

```
static class TypeDay
{
    public const int Work = 0;

    public static class Holiday
    {
        public const int Paid = 1;
        public const int NonPaid = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use flags to treat 'paid' and 'holiday' as independent properties of the enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum TypeDay{
        Na = 0,
        Work = 1,
        Holiday = 2,     
        Holiday_NonPaid = Holiday,
        Holiday_Paid = Holiday | Work 
    }
```

This assumes a workday is paid. This lets you either check the exact type, or if the day has a specific flag, `isHoliday = type.HasFlag(TypeDay.Holiday)` or `isPaid = type.HasFlag(TypeDay.Work)`.

But there are other approaches, like using classes instead of enums.The most appropriate approach will depend on the exact use case and what you want to do with the values.

Comment: This would allow `Holiday_NonPaid | Work`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I'm not sure about what your point is. If you work on a non-paid holiday it will be the same as a paid holiday, I do not think that is totally unreasonable behavior. But if that is not desired some other approach might very well be preferable.